# Problems using the Knetinhom function

Tags: r, spatstat

I get the following error:

**No crash match has been observed!
Deleting the crash from the crashList of adj_vertex has not worked!
crash_point_in_graph_as_vertex Failed!**

when I try to estimate the geometrically-corrected inhomogeneous K-function of the package spatstat.Knet for the point pattern on a linear network with the follow specifications:

Point pattern on linear network

889 points

Linear network with 199135 vertices and 243157 lines

Total length 8218901 units

Average intensity 0.0001081653 points per unit length

Unmarked

Enclosing window: rectangle = [984480.3, 1007240.4] x [987142.3, 1019317.1] units

> b <- bw.scott.iso(febrero_lpp)
>
> dfebrero <- densityQuick.lpp(febrero_lpp, sigma=b)
>
> poindfeb <- dfebrero[as.ppp(febrero_lpp)]
>
> K <- Knetinhom(febrero_lpp, lambda=poindfeb)

Can you help me to identify that is the problem?

Comment: As always it would be great if you could provide a reproducible example. Either with standard data from `spatstat` or `spatstat.Knet` or with your own data (made publicly available). This greatly increases you chances of constructive feedback.

Comment: Dear @EgeRubak, please explain to me how can I share a RData file of 35.6 MB with you in order to show you a reproducible example of this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually the best solution is that you upload the data file to something like Google Drive or Dropbox and put a link in your question as well as a short script that reads in the data and runs the analysis that generates the error. Most likely I wont have time to consider this the next days, but it is much more likely that someone else will help you if there is an easy reproducible example. Good luck!

Comment: Dear @EgeRubak please find a link from you can download a Zip file with the RData and R script for a reproducible example of the problem. Thanks in advance! [Zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5b5kc6bchybi1o/test-Knet.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. The author of the code is currently on holiday.. We will try to fix this as soon as possible.

Comment: OK, No problem! I will be waiting for a notification that the problem is already solved. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I believe the bug has been fixed now.